# Backing up WhatsApp chats

Tags: whatsapp-messenger

My WhatsApp has slowed down because of too many texts in the message database (thousands of texts in some threads). Now, I want to take a local backup of these chats for later retrieval (this part is important) and clean my WhatsApp completely. How do I do that?

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, to update your local chat backup :
Settings -> Chat backup -> Backup

Now, take a copy of `WhatsApp` folder somewhere. This will copy all your whatsapp related data - chat backups, media etc. In case you want to backup & restore only your chat backup, copy `msgstore.db.crypt12` from Whatsapp -> Databases folder.

Then, uninstall WhatsApp app and delete WhatsApp folder, i.e, "*clean my WhatsApp completely*"

Finally, copy `WhatsApp` folder back to phone storage (in case you only copied `msgstore.db.crypt12`, make Whatsapp -> Databases folders manually) then install WhatsApp app. In the setup it will say `Backup found,do you want to restore' : select yes.

Comment: How are the texts stored in memory? Are all the messages saved in a single .crypt file or they're saved in parts, distributed among all the files?

Comment: _How are the texts stored in memory?_ Don't know about that, it's encrypted by whatsapp. Yes, all the messages/chats are stored in a single .crypt file. So you only need the latest one - which will be named: `msgstore.db.crypt12`